# Wordpress get permalink function

Tags: permalinks

I would to include a Post URL in which it calls the get permalink function of the Page URL and returns it, including it in the Post URL.

So for example: Page URL http://www.example.com/test
Then the post URL is http://www.google.com/test <- the permalink from the page URL.

I am not sure if this is possible. I have tried including the get permalink code in the URLs (`http://www.google.com/<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>`) but nothing I have tried works.

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/ :

> get_permalink( int|WP_Post $post, bool $leavename = false )
>
> Retrieves the full permalink for the current post or post ID.
>
> [...]
>
> Note that *when used outside The Loop* on a posts page (index, archive,
>   etc.) without the ID parameter, it will return the URL of the last
>   post in The Loop, not the permalink for the current page.